# convert Bash command to php

Tags: php, bash

This is the bash command `echo -n x && (echo 618cf954-6576-491d-8ac6-a1b888c4705d |xxd -r -p |openssl base64|tr '/+' '_-')`

This is my php

```
<?
$uuid = "618cf954-6576-491d-8ac6-a1b888c4705d";
$voiceid = "x" . $uuid;
$voiceid  = base64_encode($voiceid);
$voiceid = str_replace("+", "-", $voiceid);
$voiceid = str_replace("/", "_", $voiceid);
echo $voiceid;
?>
```

The bash gives the right output, the php one isn't. I'm not sure what i need to do deferent in php.

The output should be `xYYz5VGV2SR2KxqG4iMRwXQ==`

A C++ version is at https://gist.github.com/1e096b658097c19cf309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, in the Bash version, the "x" isn't included in the pipe through `xxd` and `openssl`. If you want it to be then do this:

```
{ echo -n x; echo -n 618cf954-6576-491d-8ac6-a1b888c4705d; } | xxd -r -p | openssl base64 | tr '/+' '_-')
```

If, on the other hand, you want the PHP to match the existing Bash:

```
<?
$uuid = "618cf954-6576-491d-8ac6-a1b888c4
$voiceid = str_replace("-", "", $uuid);
$voiceid = pack("H*", $voiceid);
$voiceid  = base64_encode($voiceid);
$voiceid = str_replace("+", "-", $voiceid);
$voiceid = str_replace("/", "_", $voiceid);
$voiceid = "x" . $voiceid;
echo $voiceid;
?>
```

You will need to use `pack` to convert the hex string to binary.

**Edit:** Fixed several of my errors.

Comment: `echo 618cf954 |xxd -r -p |hexdump -C` shows that xxd discards the newline.

Comment: @Jander: I've revised my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you put x at the end? Prepending the x prevents conflicts with the Vivox api.

Comment: @Keverw: See the first sentence in my answer. The "x" is in your Bash version is prepended without being processed by the pipeline. There is another problem with your PHP version and that is their is no step that corresponds to the `xxd` step. By the way, this is the first you've mentioned the context.

Comment: @Keverw: Please see my edited answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following line is wrong:

```
$voiceid = "x" . $uuid;
```

Adding the "x" onto the string should be the last thing you do before the PHP `echo`.